# ifort dialect options for very old code

Tags: fortran, goto, intel-fortran

I have been suddenly given a few *very* old fortran codes to compile and get working for my research group. Using ifort when I compile the code I get the following error:`error #6526: A branch to a do-term-shared-stmt has occurred from outside the range of the corresponding inner-shared-do-construct.`

Here is the bit of code that seems to be at fault:

```
...
      IF(THRU.GT.0.D0) GO TO 120                                        00011900
      L1=LL                                                             00012000
      A1=AA                                                             00012100
      DR1=DRR                                                           00012200
      RMAX1=RMAXX                                                       00012300
      RMIN1=RMINN                                                       00012400
      IF(DR1.EQ.0.D0) DR1=DRP                                           00012500
      KMAX1=(RMAX1-RMIN1)/DR1+1.D-08                                    00012600
      IF(KMAX1.GT.NN .OR. KMAX1.LE.0) KMAX1=NN                          00012700
      RINT1=RMAX1                                                       00012800
      IF(RMAX1.NE.0.D0)                                                 00012900
     2RMAX1=DR1*DFLOAT(KMAX1)+RMIN1                                     00013000
      IUP=KMAX1                                                         00013100
      R=RMIN1                                                           00013200
      DO 120 K1=1,KMAX1                                                  00013300
      R=R+DR1                                                           00013400
      XX(K1)=R                                                           00013500
120   CONTINUE                                                          00013600
      WRITE(IW,940) NAM1,IOPT1,L1,A1,DR1,RMAX1,RMIN1,ANU1,BNU1,CNU1     00013700
121   CONTINUE                                                          00013800
...
```

Being quite unfamiliar with fortran I have been doing some searching and what I can see is that it does not like that IF statement branching to the terminal statement of the DO loop. Also, it seems that some older dialects or compilers supported this.

My questions is this: **Is there an option that will allow ifort to successfully compile this?** I.E. Is there a specific dialect compatibility option on ifort that will make this legal?

What are the side effects of that particular code on a compiler that would accept it? Is it possible that aside from the write statement the side effects are identical to going to line 121? Or was maybe the do loop supposed to go to 121?

I would consider modifying the code if not for the fact that my advisor told me that I should not make any changes whatsoever without consulting him first and so I ask this question to see if I need to consult him or not. That said if my only option is a modification to the code suggestions would be welcome for that so that I can have an idea of what needs to be done when I go to my advisor.

Comment: Anybode giving out such codes and forbiding to make them better should be condemned. The code calls for a rewrite to modern free form with the help of some automatic tool.

Comment: I agree with that but I think my advisor is afraid of changes to the functionality of the code. While the coding style is horrific, it works. It correctly calculates the single folded alpha-nucleus interaction potential which we then use in Optical Model Fits to alpha scattering data. So changes to the code would have to be validated extensively, which is a doable, but a pain and a large time sink, wholesale reformatting would probably be worse. Also, I think my advisor is afraid of hidden side effects that escape validation. In any event, I agree with you but I can see both sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll note that the code in question isn't valid even as Fortran 77, but people did weird stuff back in the mists of time.  I'll defer to any historian or person with experience.  In particular, one should be very careful to understand any subtleties in the code in relation to my "answer" here.

If we assume that the intention of the `goto` given is to jump to code *after* the execution of the loop, then I answer about minimal change to the code.

Stripping line-number comments for clarity then

```
      DO 120 K1=1,KMAX1
      R=R+DR1
      XX(K1)=R
 120  CONTINUE
      WRITE(IW,940) NAM1,IOPT1,L1,A1,DR1,RMAX1,RMIN1,ANU1,BNU1,CNU1
```

can be replaced by

```
      DO K1=1,KMAX1
      R=R+DR1
      XX(K1)=R
      END DO
 120  WRITE(IW,940) NAM1,IOPT1,L1,A1,DR1,RMAX1,RMIN1,ANU1,BNU1,CNU1
```

I would be quite surpised if the author of the code intended the loop to continue to `121`: no variable referenced by the `write` statement is updated in the loop.  It is possible that the `goto` was intended to reference `121` but I do see that many variables are not updated in the section that would be skipped.

Comment: In my searching I saw some rumblings about f66 allowing it or something, but ifort won't compile this with the -f66 flag.

Comment: Fortran 66 was well before my time, but I'll note that `-f66` doesn't (appear to) tell ifort that it should act as a Fortran 66 compiler.

Comment: As I don't fully understand ancient Fortran, I'll happily delete this answer if I'm misleading.

Comment: I have an email out to someone who got it compiled and working recently, I will see what they say and come back, that might take a day or two for the answer. So definitely leave this answer up and I will report back.

Comment: Well, the email I got in reply is singularly unhelpful, apparently the person who had compiled it before hadn't, instead they found it on a machine in their lab. So I am going to accept your answer and make the changes and see if I can get the same output, if so, I go to my advisor and talk to him, if not I go in search of f66 for a modern computer *sigh*.

Comment: Update: I changed the if statement to go to a new (unique) label which I places before the write statement. After that I ran the code on an input for which we had an output (as generated by the executable sitting on an ancient sun machine). They matched except for, in one place the sun formatted a 0.0 as 0. and the new version did 0.000000, the other non matching area was out in the 9th or 10th decimal place of some large radii values where different floating point units are generating different rounding errors. So yay it works with ifort, no to see if I can get it to work with gfortran

Comment: The reason I reused the label `120` was to save effort checking for uniqueness, and other instances of this jump.  However, if you can happily say these have been addressed then clarity from a distinct label can be useful.

Comment: Well, I wrote a quick python script that looked at the first 5 columns of every line that did not start with a 'C'. it then compiled a list of those (stripped of whitespace)it then looked for 5 digit labels,were none. So I simply used 31416 and 27183 as my identifiers (since the problem occurred in two places).